# TabView and UWP project

Tags: uwp

I got stacked with my UWP project. Here's what happened.
1.Installed Win UI by following [this MSDN article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/tab-view).
2.Added TabView, TabViewItem, TabViewItem header.
3.Visual Studio 2019 displayed 2 errors.
    - **XLS0502** The type TabView does not support direct content
    - **XDG0049** Cannot add content to an object of type TabView

Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Have you tried googling to see if anyone else has had similar issues?

Comment: @Kaz Yes, but the articles I found were too few and none of them have worked.

Answer (score 0):

You need insert `TabViewItem` into [`TabView.TabItems`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/microsoft.ui.xaml.controls.tabview.tabitems?view=winui-2.3) property like following.

```
<muxc:TabView HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <muxc:TabView.TabItems>
        <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Document 0">
            <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Placeholder" />
            </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>

        </muxc:TabViewItem>
        <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Document 1">
            <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Placeholder" />
            </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>

        </muxc:TabViewItem>
        <muxc:TabViewItem Header="Document 2">
            <muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
                <muxc:SymbolIconSource Symbol="Placeholder" />
            </muxc:TabViewItem.IconSource>
        </muxc:TabViewItem>
    </muxc:TabView.TabItems>
</muxc:TabView>
```